# Unhandeled exception when starting MongoDB - Win32

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the following message when starting mongodb on a win32 x64 machine;

```
D:\mongodb>mongod -f d:\mongodb\mongo.config
Mon Mar 03 21:23:58.549 diagLogging level=3
Mon Mar 03 21:23:58.550   diagLogging couldn't open D:\mongodb\data/diaglog.5314
f2ee
Mon Mar 03 21:23:58.550 *** unhandled exception 0xE06D7363 at 0x76C7C41F, termin
ating
Mon Mar 03 21:23:58.551 *** stack trace for unhandled exception:
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.018 KERNELBASE.dll
                       RaiseException+0x58
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.018 mongod.exe      f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebu
ild\eh\throw.cpp(157)  _CxxThrowException+0x48
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.018 mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(1322)
                       mongo::DiagLog::openFile+0x156
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.018 mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\instance.cpp(1334)
                       mongo::DiagLog::setLevel+0x80
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.018 mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(998)
                       processCommandLineOptions+0xff0
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.018 mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(1274)
                       mongoDbMain+0x123
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.019 mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(727)
                       main+0x14
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.019 mongod.exe      f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\c
rt0.c(278)             __tmainCRTStartup+0x10b
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.019 kernel32.dll
                       BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.019 ntdll.dll
                       RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.020 writing minidump diagnostic file mongo.dmp
Mon Mar 03 21:23:59.101 *** immediate exit due to unhandled exception
```

Any one have any idea what is causing this??

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the data folder at location "D:\mongodb\data"?  And is the folder accessible?

Comment: @Jake Evans : Did you get any solution for this?
I'm getting this issue now.

Answer (score 2):

Clear your data folder and try again. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. 
In my case the issue was that the drive was full and mongoDB could not write its minidumps. 
I just had to free up some space and the database was fine.

Answer (score 0):

please create the folder structure manually D:\mongodb\data

Answer (score 0):

Run `cmd` as admin and run:

```
mongod --dbpath "bin path"
```

Then open another `cmd` in your data directory and run:

```
mongo
```